# How to count distinct items on specific fields in QueryDSL

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, querydsl

*Edit: it turns out that JPA can't express this. The solution was to rewrite in SQL.*

I'm using QueryDSL to perform an aggregate query on a JPA data set for reporting. I have no problem extracting the report data. For example:

```
...
query = query.groupBy(QVehicle.vehicle.make, QVehicle.vehicle.model);
return query.listDistinct(new QMakeModelReportData(
            QVehicle.vehicle.make, QVehicle.vehicle.model,
            QVehicle.vehicle.make.count()));
```

This produces a list of my DTO object, each of which contains a vehicle make, vehicle model, and the count of vehicles of that make model. Like this:

```
   Ford, Focus, 14
   Ford, Mondeo, 4
   Vauxhall, Astra, 4
```

But I can't work out the syntax to count the number of rows before I actually perform the query. The syntax I imagine is like this, which doesn't exist:

```
return query.countDistinct(QVehicle.vehicle.make, QVehicle.vehicle.model);
```

I've ended up with a rather inefficient option:

```
return query
    .listDistinct(QVehicle.vehicle.make, QVehicle.vehicle.model)
    .size();
```

Is there anything better?

Comment: Are you able to express what you need via JPQL directly?

Comment: That's what I'll be trying on Monday morning. I'm also considering going underneath JPA and doing the query in SQL, where it's very easy to express.

Comment: I think I need to reach an equivalent of this SQL, probably using a subquery: `select sum(count) from  (select count(*) from vehicle v group by v.make,v.model) as subquery;` I'm not sure this (or the even simpler `select count(distinct v.make || v.model) from vehicle v;` ) is expressible in JPQL.

Comment: Just a historical note - JPA can't express what I needed, so I switched to SQL for the query. Not a QueryDSL problem.

Comment: Adrian: your update would do an acceptable answer. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a QueryDSL limitation, but a JPA limitation. The solution was to rewrite in SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `query.select(q.field.countDistinct())`

Comment: I am attempting to count distinct on multiple fields, not a single field. JPA is limited to performing count distinct on a single field only: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37784831/184998