# JPA count distinct multiple expressions

Tags: jpa, count, eclipselink, multiple-columns

CriteriaBuilder.countDistinct(Expression e)

It takes one expression only. How to count distinct multiple expressions? For example,

```
Country              Language
-------------------------------
```

In JPA CriteriaQuery, how to count different pairs of (country, language)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with JPQL. JPQL BNF is very clear

```
aggregate_expression ::= { AVG | MAX | MIN | SUM } ([DISTINCT] state_field_path_expression) |
    COUNT ([DISTINCT] identification_variable | state_field_path_expression |
    single_valued_object_path_expression)
```

Comment: I do not know why JPA lacks this common feature. Is there way to combine multiple expressions into one expression? Thanks.